# Fazer embed para o conteúdo do meu site

Tags: html5, css3

Tenho um site no qual tenho citações, já tenho a estrutura html com a url no formato, www.site.com.br/embed/uiJh porém, se eu fornecer o código com esse url em um iframe, eu tenho que especificar sempre o tamanho correto do height no iframe, mas tem citações que são maiores que as outras. Como que eu posso fazer igual o youtube faz? Se eu coloco o width e height no iframe, o conteúdo se enquadra no iframe?

Pois eu preciso fornecer somente o código do iframe, então as modificações teriam que ser feitas na página do meu site.

Alguém sabe como que eu posso fazer?

Comment: Isto vai ser cross-domain?

Comment: Sim, esse código do embed será colocado em vários sites.

Answer (score 1):

Me parece que a sua idéia é fornecer conteúdo para outros sites, então eu utilizaria uma solução cross domain.

http://davidjbradshaw.github.io/iframe-resizer/

Esta biblioteca utiliza o método `window.postMessage` que possibilita o cross domain com segurança.

Funciona para navegadores acima do IE8.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.postMessage

Comment: Ola Marcelo, vou verificar esse link que me passou, parece que vai funcionar para mim, esse script eu tenho que colocar na minha página e parece que servirá para o meu intento. Obrigado

Comment: Minha dúvida maior nessa ferramenta é que o usuário teria que ter o iframeResizer.contentWindow.min.js no site dele também, mas com o código embed não tem como eu disponibilizar esse código. Eu teria que deixar esse código juntamente com o código do iframe para o usuário copiar? Tem como eu fazer de alguma outra forma?

Answer (score 0):

Ao invés de fazer uso de um IFRAME, você pode tentar carregar dinamicamente o HTML renderizado da página remota para um elemento da página atual.

Segue um exemplo em jQuery:

```
$("#minhaDivVLocal").load("minhapaginaexterna.html");
```

Comment: Ola OnoSendai, no caso precisaria do embed pois isso será disponibilizado no site, para que usuários possam colocar o código no site deles, no mesmo pensamento do youtube mesmo.

Comment: @tvieira agradeço o esclarecimento - eu entendi sua pergunta de outra maneira.

Answer (score 0):

Uma boa forma de criar um embed é através de javascript, ao invés de usar iframe e ficar preso ao tamanho do content.

**Seu embed pode ficar com essa estrutura:**

```
<div class="widget">
    <div id="widget-content">Carregando...</div>
    <!-- seu script que carrega o conteudo do link e exiba na div widget-content -->
    <script async src="http://www.site.com.br/embed/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</div>
```